# Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::result()

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

I get this fatal error when I convert array to object using type conversion. Then apply `result()` to the object. Here is the function in my model:

```
function exists($id) {
    $query = $this->sca_model->getWhere('dff', array('_id' => $id));

    $object = (object)$query;
    $result = $object->result();

    if ($result)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

What is missing here or is there any other method to convert array to object in with `result()` can be used, and yes I used `json_decode()` too. But has the same error.

Comment: What is `result` method? BTW, `stdClass` does not have anything like that.

Comment: `result()` : This function returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure. Typically you'll use this in a foreach loop. [result()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Comment: So, you need (1) a class definition which includes that result function (2) that class should be able to set some variables based on an array argument. Well, create that class.

Comment: `result()` is a built-in function in DB_result.php file of code igniter framework .`public function result($type = 'object')
 {
  if ($type == 'array') return $this->result_array();
  else if ($type == 'object') return $this->result_object();
  else return $this->custom_result_object($type);
 }` . These files a included auotload time so their is some other problem.

Comment: @Vikas_web Do you know what casting array to object does?

Comment: @Leri is their any loss of data in this ?? explain what is my mistake ??

Comment: @Vikas_web Read up on [_converting to object_](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting) part.

Comment: thanks @Leri i got that poit .. now its working nice ..